# Using [weak self] and assignment in Swift closure

Tags: ios, closures, swift

I've been playing around with Swift and got AFNetworking integrated into a project and have got a bit of code that I'm not particularly happy with.

Having [already posted](https://devforums.apple.com/message/978938#978938) on the Apple dev forums and got no reply, I thought I'd bring it to SO...

My class has a strong reference to an `AFHTTPSessionManager` instance and the following snippet is a closure used in a call to the `GET(_, parameters, success, failure)` method.

```
let failure = { [weak self] (task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, error: NSError!) -> (Void) in
    if error?.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey]?.statusCode == 401 {
        if let weakSelf = self {
            weakSelf.error = NSError(domain: MyConnectionErrorDomain, code: ErrorCode.InvalidCredentials.toRaw(), userInfo: nil)
            weakSelf.state = .Error
        }
    }
}
```

Is this way of using `[weak self]` in a closure along with the `if let` syntax correct when I need to mutate the `error` and `state` variables of `self`? I'm guessing it is as `self` may have gone away before the closure gets executed. I can't use `self?.error = ...` as that gives a compiler error.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it.  You can use optional chaining if you're just reading properties, but you can't write through chaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With of Xcode 6 beta 5, you can now [do assignments via optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_360). You can even check if the assignment was done by checking the return value of the assignment:

```
if (self?.error = NSError(domain: MyConnectionErrorDomain, code: ErrorCode.InvalidCredentials.toRaw(), userInfo: nil)) == nil {
    // `self` became nil in the meantime
}
```

**Update**: I just tried optional binding `if var` and it does seem to work in beta 5:

```
if var strongSelf = self {
    // ...
}
```